# ExtJS - Dynamically Format GridPanel rows?

Tags: extjs

I have records with a boolean value, and depending on the boolean value, I would like the GridPanel's rows to be rendered bold.  I'm sure there is a nice GridView style way to do this but I can't seem to find it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your answer is correct, but I want to point out that there's no need to provide an instantiated GridView instance in order to override getRowClass.  Use the GridPanel's [`viewConfig`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-cfg-viewConfig) instead:

```
viewConfig: {
    getRowClass: function(rec, idx, rowPrms, ds) {
        return rec.data.isRead === false ? 'ph-bold-row' : '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind:

```
view: new Ext.grid.GridView({
            getRowClass: function(rec, idx, rowPrms, ds) {
                return rec.data.isRead === false ? 'ph-bold-row' : '';
            }
        })
```